# Master Slider Google Analytics event tracking

Tags: wordpress, url, google-analytics

I'm facing problem with adding Google Analytics Event tracking code to Wordpress Master Slider url. In Master Slider Slider settings there's field to put Slide URL
I put there this code:

```
http://some-link.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Slider Link', 'Gdzie na joge');"
```

it outputs:

```
<a href="http://some-link.com&quot;%20onclick=&quot;ga('send',%20'event',%20'Slider%20Link',%20'Gdzie%20na%20joge');&quot;" class="ms-slide-link"></a>
```

Is there a way to make it work? Without tracking code it output like this:

```
<a href="http://some-link.com" class="ms-slide-link"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can track events

1. You could add a jQuery / javascript listener that listen for clicks on this element.
2. You could use GTM which would make thing much easier.

A quick guide to setting up GTM
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en

Event tracking in GTM: https://marketlytics.com/blog/google-tag-manager-events-complete-guide

hope this helped you